# TypeORM basic join explanation

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

According to typeorm [guide](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#inner-and-left-joins)

I don't understand this part very well:

```
(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
```

what does mean type? what does mean photo => photo. ? . it's not good explained on the link.

Partial code:

```
Import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany} from "typeorm";
import {Photo} from "./Photo";

@Entity()
export class User {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];
}
```

and on the code:

```
const user = await createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")
    .where("user.name = :name", { name: "Timber" })
    .getOne();
```

from where comes ""user.photos"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First question: `(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)`

The decorator for `@OneToMany`takes two functions, first one returns the related Entity, the second, returns the related entity's "foreign key" property.  Since "type" isn't even used you actually don't need it.  I omit type completely using `@OneToMany(()=> Photo, photo => photo.user)`  Hasn't been an issue for me.

Second question: `where comes "user.photos"`

The `leftJoinAndSelect("user.photos", "photo")` references the property `photos` defined in the User entity.  It's the last line in the User class.